# Expose a base class function in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to invoke a function declared in a base class but I am unable to invoke from **QML**, Here's an example of my code

**R.cpp**

```cpp
class R
{

public:
    virtual void startGui() = 0;
    void  toggleCameraView();

};

void R::toggleCameraView(){
  //do stuff
}
```

**G.cpp**

```cpp
class G : public R
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
  void startGui();
};

void G::startGui(){

  QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
  ctxt->setContextProperty("g", this);
}
```

**main.qml**

```
function toggleCameraView(){
    g.toggleCameraView()
}
```

This is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: Property 'toggleCameraView' of object G(0x2838a8) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not provided an MCVE I will not point out the cause of the error regarding your code. Instead I will show a workable example.

If you want a method to be accessible from QML this has to be a slot or Q_INVOKABLE, I will use this last method in my example:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>

class R: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    virtual void startGui() = 0;
    Q_INVOKABLE void  toggleCameraView();
};

void R::toggleCameraView()
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
}

class G: public R
{
public:
    G(QObject *parent=nullptr): R(parent){
        startGui();
        const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
        engine.load(url);
    }
    void startGui() override;
private:
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
};

void G::startGui()
{
    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("g", this);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    G g;

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Component.onCompleted: g.toggleCameraView()
}
```

Output:

```
toggleCameraView
```

Comment: @Gebre If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleCameraView(){
    g3.toggleCameraView()
}
```

why is "g3" ? it should be "g", the same name in `ctxt->setContextProperty("g", this);`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, it was a typo, I just edited it